# Ajax dropdown limit to list

Tags: asp.net, ajax, controls

pretty much what the title says.

I am using an Ajax Drop Down as illustrated here:

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/DropDown/DropDown.aspx

using linkbuttons ... is there a way to limit to list?

Thank you.

Edit: I think it was VB 6 maybe that you could select "LimitToList" in a drop down. Meaning the user can only select the values in the drop down and not enter his own data.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by limit to list?

Comment: I see no way to enter my own data in the example, what type of control are you extending?

Comment: it is a text box, I suppose maybe if you don't allow the text box to get focus? Let me try brb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're extending a textbox, I think the best option would be to attach an event listener that voids keypresses, you could do this in the ASPX:

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtFoo" onkeypress="return false;" runat="server"/>
```

Or, in the code behind:

```
txtFoo.Attributes.Add("OnKeyPress","return false;");
```

This will prevent a user from typing in the textbox, essentially creating the effect you want.

A bonus side effect is that a user is allowed to free type an entry if javascript is disabled and the dropdown extender doesn't work.